# How to find what values of x and y create the greatest value of $\ z$ where $\ z=(x+1)y$ and $\ 20x+5y=1000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the the values of x and y that create the greatest value of $z$ where

$z=(x+1)y$

$20x+5y=1000$

assuming $x$ and $y$ are positive. I tried a few 3D calculators but the ones I found only graph one function at a time. I can't see a way to solve this other than trial and error.

Comment: Solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ using the second equation, and then you must maximize a quadratic function of $x$

Comment: A technique learned in multivariable calculus for this scenario is Lagrange multipliers, but that's not needed for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the second equation, $y=200-4x$, so we have to maximize

$z=(x+1)(200-4x)=-4(x+1)(x-50)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for